# Why fuzzy query returns a match but query with fuzziness doesn't on the same input?

Tags: elasticsearch, string-matching

I created the following index in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT /my-index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "3_5_edgegrams"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "3_5_edgegrams": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I inserted the following document:

```json
{
  "name": "Nuvus Gro Corp"
}
```

When I make the following query (let's call it `fuzzy_query`):

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "name": {
        "value": "qnuv"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get a match for the above document.

When I make the query (let's call the query `match_with_fuzziness`):

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "qnuv",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get a match. If I make the following query:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "nuvq",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I again get a match. I don't understand why when I make the `match_with_fuzziness` query I don't get any matches.

**EDIT:** I analyzed the queries with Kibana Profiler and according to the profiler `match_with_fuzziness` is a `SynonymQuery Synonym(name:qnu name:qnuv)`  query while `fuzzy_query` is a `BoostQuery (name:nuv)^0.6666666`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar problem to the one explained in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379994/why-string-longer-than-max-gram-is-matched-in-elasticsearch).

The problem is that you haven't specified a specific `search_analyzer`, so at search time `qnuv` and `nuvq` also get analyzed by `my_analyzer` and edge-ngramed as well, hence the match you're receiving.

If we check the first query, since you're using the `fuzzy` query, `qnuv` (the search term) will match `nuv` (the first indexed edge-ngramed token) with a distance of 1 (i.e. the first `q` is "tolerated"), which is what the `fuzzy` query does by default (with ["fuzziness: AUTO"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness))

In the third query, `nuv` (the first edge-ngramed token of the search term) will match `nuv` (the first indexed edge-ngramed token).

The case of the second query is a bit special and I'm referencing below how the [`fuzziness` parameter works in the context of `match` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness)

> Fuzzy matching is not applied to terms with synonyms or **in cases where the analysis process produces multiple tokens at the same position**. Under the hood these terms are expanded to a special synonym query that blends term frequencies, which does not support fuzzy expansion.

The part in bold is what applies to your case. Since the search term `qnuv` is analyzed by `my_analyzer`, it produces the two tokens `qnu` and `qnuv` at the same position and that does not support fuzzy matching.

You need to change your mapping to this one instead and it will work the way you expect, i.e. all three queries will return your document:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"          <---- add this line
      }
    }
  }
```