# Why string longer than max_gram is matched in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I created the following index in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "3_5_edgegrams"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "3_5_edgegrams": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "test": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I inserted the document:

```
POST /test/_doc
{
  "test": "Tesla General Motors GeneralGeneralGeneral"
}
```

and made the following query:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "test": "general"
    }
  }
}
```

and received a hit with the original document I inserted earlier. I'm wondering how this can be given the fact that `max_gram` value is 3 on the `test` field. This can be confirmed with the term vector API response:

```
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "XDNdpXoBdvOxOZmY8RLm",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "took" : 0,
  "term_vectors" : {
    "test" : {
      "field_statistics" : {
        "sum_doc_freq" : 9,
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "sum_ttf" : 12
      },
      "terms" : {
        "g" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 2,
          "term_freq" : 2,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 1,
              "start_offset" : 6,
              "end_offset" : 13
            },
            {
              "position" : 3,
              "start_offset" : 21,
              "end_offset" : 42
            }
          ]
        },
        "ge" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 2,
          "term_freq" : 2,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 1,
              "start_offset" : 6,
              "end_offset" : 13
            },
            {
              "position" : 3,
              "start_offset" : 21,
              "end_offset" : 42
            }
          ]
        },
        "gen" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 2,
          "term_freq" : 2,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 1,
              "start_offset" : 6,
              "end_offset" : 13
            },
            {
              "position" : 3,
              "start_offset" : 21,
              "end_offset" : 42
            }
          ]
        },
        "m" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 2,
              "start_offset" : 14,
              "end_offset" : 20
            }
          ]
        },
        "mo" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 2,
              "start_offset" : 14,
              "end_offset" : 20
            }
          ]
        },
        "mot" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 2,
              "start_offset" : 14,
              "end_offset" : 20
            }
          ]
        },
        "t" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 0,
              "start_offset" : 0,
              "end_offset" : 5
            }
          ]
        },
        "te" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 0,
              "start_offset" : 0,
              "end_offset" : 5
            }
          ]
        },
        "tes" : {
          "doc_freq" : 1,
          "ttf" : 1,
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 0,
              "start_offset" : 0,
              "end_offset" : 5
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I'm wondering why do I get a hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't specified a specific `search_analyzer`, so at search time `general` also gets analyzed by `my_analyzer` and ngramed as well, hence the match you're receiving.

You need to change your mapping to this one instead and it will work the way you expect:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "test": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"          <---- add this line
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have another bounty open for this question which I think will have a similar answer but not sure. In case you're interested https://stackoverflow.com/q/68350177

Comment: Sure, but maybe let's close this one first ;-)